# Reference cannot be initialized/expression must have type class

Tags: c++, reference

I'm doing a quick binary tree program as a homework, but I am getting weird errors that I can't seem to figure out how to fix. Normally I'm programming in C#, and C is just slightly different but different enough for me to get confused.

Here is the code that is giving the error:

```
void SortArray() {//bubble sorting by float value of 'b'
int flag = 0;

do {
    flag = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++)
    {
        if (stubList[i].b > stubList[i + 1].b) {
            Swap(stubList[i], stubList[i + 1]);
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
} while (flag == 0);

printf("Sorted by value of variable 'b'"); _getch(); _getch();
}
```

And here is the whole script:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct stub
{
    char crown[51];//some custom name - can be empty
    float b;//comparable value for tree sort
    int c;//limited by maxint
    stub *l;//left node(normally smaller "b" value than this node)
    stub *r;//right node(normally bigger "b" value than this node)
};

stub *stubList[255];//empty list of a stub array with a safe casual amount
int arraySize = 0;

stub *head = NULL;//main stub(first)
stub *latest = NULL;//latest stub

stub *st = NULL;//used for creating and checking

FILE *fs = NULL;
char fileName[255];

int maxint = 20;//for var 'c'

void BTreeNodeToArray(stub *s) {
    stubList[arraySize] = s;

    arraySize++;
}

void Swap(stub &s1, stub &s2) {
    stub temp = s2;

    s1 = s2;
    s2 = temp;
}

int MaxMin(int num) {
    int clampedInt = num;
    if (num < 0) clampedInt = 0;
    else if (num > maxint) clampedInt = maxint;

    return clampedInt;
}

//Create a completely new stub with crown, b, and c variables being filled here
void CreateElement() {
    st = new stub;
    printf("Adding information for node:\n");
    printf("Node name: "); gets_s(st->crown);
    printf("\n");

    float f;
    printf("Node float value (B): "); scanf_s("%f", &f);
    st->b = f;
    printf("\n");

    int d;
    printf("Node integer value (C): "); scanf_s("%d", &d);
    st->c = d;
    printf("\n");
    st->c = MaxMin(st->c);

    st->l = NULL;
    st->r = NULL;
}

//creates the very first stub(root/head)
void CreateFirst() {
    printf("First in tree. Adding root node...\n");

    CreateElement();
    head = st;
    latest = head;
    BTreeNodeToArray(head);

    printf("Added head stub\ncrown: %s\nValue: %f\nExtra: %d", head->crown, head->b, head->c);
    getchar();
    getchar();
}

void AddStub() {
    if (head == NULL) {
        CreateFirst();
    }
    else {
        CreateElement();//create newest node
        latest = st;
        st = head;
        int depth = 0;
        while (1) {
            if ((latest->b <= st->b)) {//choose left if true
                printf("Went left\n");
                depth++;
                if (st->l == NULL) {//node free, assign here
                    printf("Node assigned at depth %d\n", depth);
                    st->l = latest;
                    BTreeNodeToArray(latest);
                    getchar();
                    getchar();
                    break;
                }
                else {//loop again with next node
                    //printf("New loop (left)\n");
                    st = st->l;
                }
            }
            else {//choose right
                printf("Went right\n");
                depth++;
                if (st->r == NULL) {//node free, assign here
                    printf("Node assigned at depth %d\n", depth);
                    st->r = latest;
                    BTreeNodeToArray(latest);
                    getchar();
                    getchar();
                    break;
                }
                else {//loop again with next node
                    //printf("New loop (right)\n");
                    st = st->r;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void ViewArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        printf_s("Node [%d]:\n\tCrown: %s\n\tweight: %f\n\tExta value(0 - %d): %d\n", i, stubList[i]->crown, stubList[i]->b, maxint, stubList[i]->c);
    }
    getchar();
}

void SortArray() {//bubble sorting by float value of 'b'
    int flag = 0;

    do {
        flag = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++)
        {
            if (stubList[i].b > stubList[i + 1].b) {
                Swap(stubList[i], stubList[i + 1]);
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    } while (flag == 0);

    printf("Sorted by value of variable 'b'"); _getch(); _getch();
}

void ProcessArray() {
    char c = ' ';
    int found = 0;

    printf("Process with character: \n"); c = _getch();

    if (arraySize <= 0) {
        printf("No List!");
        return;
    }

    char chkstr[5];
    for (short i = 0; i < 5; i++)//simple assign to a 'string' 5 times
    {
        chkstr[i] = c;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        if (strstr(stubList[i]->crown, chkstr) != NULL) {
            // contains
            printf("B = %f at [%d] \n", stubList[i]->b, i);
            found++;
        }
    }

    if (found > 0) {
        printf("---Found: %d with character %c---", found, c);
    }
    else {
        printf("No elements found with '%c'", c);
    }
    getchar();
}

void ExportArray() {
    FILE *fs = NULL;
    char fileName[255];
    errno_t err;

    printf("Save to file as: \n"); gets_s(fileName);

    if (strlen(fileName) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to create file. File name empty!");
        _getch();
        _getch();
    }

    err = fopen_s(&fs, fileName, "wb");
    if (err != 0) {
        printf("Failed to create file!!!");
        _getch();
        _getch();
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        int written = fwrite(&stubList[i], sizeof(stub), 1, fs);
        //fwrite(&gr[i], sizeof(student), 1, fs);
    }
    int numclosed = _fcloseall();

    printf("Exported to file: %s", fileName);
    getchar();
}

void CleanReset() {//reset all values and release memory (function used for import)
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        delete stubList[i];
    }

    arraySize = 0;
    st = NULL;
    head = NULL;
    latest = NULL;
}

void ImportArray() {
    FILE *fs = NULL;
    char fname[255];
    errno_t err;

    printf("Open FIle: "); gets_s(fname);

    err = fopen_s(&fs, fname, "rb");
    if (err == 0) {
        CleanReset();

        fseek(fs, 0, SEEK_END);
        long size = ftell(fs);
        arraySize = size / sizeof(stub);//get amount of students saved
        fseek(fs, 0, SEEK_SET);

        int i = 0;

        st = new stub;
        fread_s(&st, sizeof(stub), sizeof(stub), 1, fs);
        stubList[i] = st;
        while (!feof(fs)) {
            i++;
            st = new stub;
            fread_s(&st, sizeof(stub), sizeof(stub), 1, fs);
            stubList[i] = st;
        }

        printf("File data imported. Size: %d", arraySize);
        getchar();
        return;
    }

    printf("Failed to import file!!!");
    getchar();
}

void main()
{
    system("chcp 65001");//use utf8

    char izb = 'i';

    while (izb != '0') {
        system("cls");

        printf_s("1. Add stub\n");
        printf_s("2. View Array\n");
        printf_s("3. Sort Array\n");
        printf_s("4. Process\n");
        printf_s("5. Export array to file\n");
        printf_s("6. Import array from file\n");
        printf_s("0. Exit\n\n");

        printf_s("Choose action:\n"); izb = _getch();

        switch (izb)
        {
        case '1':
            AddStub();
            break;
        case '2':
            ViewArray();
            break;
        case '3':
            SortArray();
            break;
        case '4':
            ProcessArray();
            break;
        case '5':
            ExportArray();
            break;
        case '6':
            ImportArray();
            break;
        case '0':
            //Exit();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are several things in your code, which are not C, but C++ (`new`, `stub` instead of `struct stub` and pass by reference). Are you sure that you write C code?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Request like this "*help as soon as possible because im short on time.*" typically do not accelerate things, but provoke the opposite, so better take care.

Comment: Show the error message with exact line numbers.

Comment: `stubList[i].b` should be `stubList[i]->b` because a stublist[i] is a *stub rather than a stub.

Comment: C++ is not "slightly" different from C#, and C is even more different – the similarities are mainly punctuation and the spelling of some keywords. I would say that they're *similar* enough to get you confused.

Comment: Its normally C but just by thought, I suppose. The teachers at the university dont really care if its C or C++ haha

Comment: @MarkPlotnick what about `Swap(stubList[i], stubList[i + 1]);` ?

Comment: The conversation under the answer below indicate to me that this question is too broad, and that some debugging would be necessary to narrow down where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you want to pass a `stub *` to a function that wants a `stub &`. The first one is a pointer, the second one is a reference.

You have two options.

First option (imho recommended):

Change your swap function to accept pointers instead of references.

```
void Swap(stub *s1, stub *s2) {
    stub temp = *s2;

    *s1 = *s2;
    *s2 = temp;
}
```

Second option:

Dereference the parameters before passing to swap:

```
Swap(*(stubList[i]), *(stubList[i + 1]));
```

You have to undestand that the datatype in your list is a pointer to stub, the function `Swap` wants a reference, which are different things in C++.

For a better understanding I recommend reading this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-vs-references-cpp/

Comment: Ahh thanks a ton! So I missed to change the Swap function to a pointer.
I found one more bug when I was messing around in the console: The ImportArray function breaks the array list, saying memory violation.
Might it be because it is a pointer stub inside the stub and the pointer after import is just pointing at the wrong memory spot? If so, any way to fix it?

Comment: Use a debugger to figure that out.

Comment: I dont really have an idea how to debug , to be honest xD

Comment: Then learn it. Its one of the most important tools you have... and something like a segfault is really easy to identify with a debugger attached.

Comment: Thats the thing though, I got 2 weeks(max 4) to learn C, and it doesnt really give enough time for anything, especially if I cant focus entirely on that

Comment: I am sorry to put it that way, but that is no reason for me to do your work ^^. I got deadlines, too. If you want success on SO, then you should show effort. Everyone is glad to help. Everyone gets angry when told "do my homework". Also this is C++ and not C.

Comment: If you don't learn the debugger for this program, you'll need to for the next program.  Virtually everyone starting out using pointers in C makes mistakes.

Comment: Thats the thing. Pointer are a pain in the ass until it makes "click" and you understand them. After the "click" pointers are the shit to go for :)